# WIFI not showing up in OS

Tags: wifi, drivers, internet, amd

good afternoon to you, so I have installed Elementary OS and find it very beautiful however it seems like the OS does not recognize my WI-FI adapter.

I am using a Lenovo Ideapad 3 and I do not have an ethernet port on this laptop. I was going to use the following commands to install the drivers for the adapter but no internet I'm not sure how I would even get the drivers unless I put them on a USB?

this is the website I'm going off, does someone have any idea what I could do in this situation?

https://elementary-os-solutions.blogspot.com/2019/01/wifi-not-working-in-elementary-os-juno.html

Comment: Could you update your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C network` and `sudo lspci`? This will include some specific details about the hardware that will make it much easier to offer a specific solution.

Comment: You can buy a USB wifi dongle (they are quite cheap, even under $10) and use that to connect to internet and install whatever you need to fix your internal wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the look of Elementary but had the same problem - no wifi. I'm also on an ideapad. There is a further difficulty in that Elementary does not recognize my phone for tethering to the net for downloading drivers so I doubt that it will accept a Wi-Fi dongle/adapter, and don't want to waste even 10$. I may be wrong of course, but what it does mean is I won't be installing until this is addressed. Of note; Ideapads will accept most Linux distros but they have obstacles around loading some, and frequently wifi drivers are a problem. I'm currently using Zorin, and it does accept tethering as a way to download the Wifi driver.